# Drap and drop in Xamarin forms with short press

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I've added drag and drop gesture to a xamarin forms app following microsoft doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop

Everything works as expected.
Drag is initiated by a long press.

I would like to change this behavior by initiating a drag with a short press.

Is it possible ?

Comment: No, I think it is by design and there is no such api for you to change the behavior  so far. Since drag and drop gesture recognizer is currently experimental, you can raise a feature request in github,

Comment: Tks, I'll create a feature request

Comment: feature request link : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12627

Comment: Thanks, you can wait for response there.